# Records retrieved twice

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following php/mySQL code:

```
$wp_sql_query_text = "SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table1.field3,
table2.field1, table2.field2,table3.field1, table3.field2 from table1

INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field2=table2.field1 
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.field3=table3.field1 
WHERE table1.field1 > SOME_VALUE
ORDER BY table1field1";


echo $wp_sql_query_text;    
$get_app_history = mysqli_query($conn,$wp_sql_query_text);
$app_entry = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_app_history);

//some additional code for initialization of counters and variables

while ($app_entry = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_app_history)){
    //some processing
}
```

Simply put

> 1) There are 3 tables - table1, table2 and table3.
>
> 2) table1 has 3 fields - field1, field2 and field3.
>
> 3) table2 and table3 have 2 fields

each.

After 'echo'ing the sql query, I cut and pasted the sql in my phpmyadmin and records are retrieved only once.

However, on my page, I get the same record retrieved twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are fetching your result twice

```
$app_entry = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_app_history);  // first fetch

.......some additional code for initialization of kounters and variables.....

while ($app_entry = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_app_history)) // second fetch with a loop
```

I would suggest to remove first and keep the loop that you might use in case of multiple results